# Get unique add to cart from GA v4 API

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

Using GA data analytics API, we can get "addToCarts" metric

However that's total add to carts

On GA web, we can see total add to cart events and also total users that added to cart:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO2ci.png)

And as you can see the numbers can be very different because one user can do many add to carts...

How can we get unique add to carts from API?

Thank you

I am trying to get unique add to carts, but getting total add to carts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it. We need to use the dimension `eventName` And the metric `totalUsers`. Then we can do `dimensionFilter` by `eventName` for the `add_to_cart` event.

And the result is the unique `add_to_carts`!